# I Get an error when using samplegrabber with smarttee

Tags: c#, directshow

```
graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
//Create the Capture Graph Builder
ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraphBuilder = null;
captureGraphBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();

//Create the media control for controlling the graph
mediaControl = (IMediaControl)this.graphBuilder;

// Attach the filter graph to the capture graph
int hr = captureGraphBuilder.SetFiltergraph(this.graphBuilder);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

//Add the Video input device to the graph
hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(theDevice, "source filter");
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


//Add the Video compressor filter to the graph
hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(theCompressor, "compressor filter");
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);


//////////// Smart Tee
IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
graphBuilder.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");

IPin outPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(theDevice, PinDirection.Output, 0);
IPin inPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(smartTeeFilter, PinDirection.Input, 0);
graphBuilder.Connect(outPin, inPin);



/////
ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;
IBaseFilter baseGrabFilter = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
graphBuilder.AddFilter(baseGrabFilter, "Grabber");


IPin sourcePin, grabPin;
sourcePin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(theDevice, PinDirection.Output, 0);
grabPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFilter, PinDirection.Input, 0);
graphBuilder.Connect(sourcePin, grabPin);

graphBuilder.Render(DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0));
ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(baseGrabFilter, "Ds.NET Grabber");
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        ////

SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);
```

Here, I am getting an error titled "The operation cannot be performed because the pins are not connected." Where is My problem?! I am trying to add an overlay Text to captured video and then save it.
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
hr = captureGraphBuilder.RenderStream(null, null, smartTeeFilter, null, null);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `sourcePin` and `outPin` variables with the same pin exactly. So you are trying to connect a pin which is already connected.

Answer (score 0):

connect pins like this:

```
FilterGraphTools.ConnectFilters(graphBuilder, inPin, outPin);
```